# Are the internal drives on a MacPro3,1 hot swappable?

Tags: mac-pro, sata

I believe SATA drives were designed to be hot swappable, but I imagine there might still be some hardware restrictions.

So if you were to unmount a drive, can you swap out a drive in one of the internal drive sleds while the machine is on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 12 years of owning Mac Pros, I've never tried this.

MacRumors, however, says a resounding "**No**". Don't do it.

Apparently the protocol supports it but the hardware must too. XServes supported it, Pros don't.

Relevant threads…
[Can you Insert Drive While Running Mac Pro ??](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/can-you-insert-drive-while-running-mac-pro.706338/)
[How to rescan SATA ports without restarting?](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/how-to-rescan-sata-ports-without-restarting.2188432/)

I also found on ArsTechnica - [Did I fry my Mac Pro?](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=1331165)

Comment: The links you provided (especially the last one 'did I fry...') indicate that while hot swap in SATA is a feature, it has to be implemented in the computer hardware as well - the Xserve did have this, but the MacPro did not. Thanks!